# Extract information of kubernetes annotations with jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

I have this JSON code:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "autoscaling/v1",
    "kind": "HorizontalPodAutoscaler",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics": "[{\"type\":\"Resource\",\"resource\":{\"name\":\"memory\",\"targetAverageValue\":\"400Mi\"}}]",
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"autoscaling/v2beta1\",\"kind\":\"HorizontalPodAutoscaler\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"pdn-location-suscriber\",\"namespace\":\"pdn-oms\"},\"spec\":{\"maxReplicas\":3,\"metrics\":[{\"resource\":{\"name\":\"cpu\",\"targetAverageUtilization\":100},\"type\":\"Resource\"},{\"resource\":{\"name\":\"memory\",\"targetAverageValue\":\"400Mi\"},\"type\":\"Resource\"}],\"minReplicas\":1,\"scaleTargetRef\":{\"apiVersion\":\"extensions/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"name\":\"location-suscriber\"}}}\n"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to obtain the value of `targetAverageValue = 400Mi` that is in `"autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics"`, so how create a JSONPath expression to extract that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `extract` the information using `jq`. 
Just run the following command.

```sh
$ kubectl get hpa <hpa-name> -o=json | jq '.metadata.annotations["autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics"]' | jq -r | jq '.[].resource.targetAverageValue'
```

Also you can try the following.

```sh
$ kubectl get hpa <hpa-name> -o=jsonpath="{.metadata.annotations.autoscaling\.alpha\.kubernetes\.io\/metrics}" | jq '.[].resource.targetAverageValue'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use this expression to get your desired value.

```
kubectl get hpa pdn-location-suscriber(your_hpa_name) -n pdn-oms -o jsonpath="{.spec.metrics[1].resource.targetAverageValue}"
```

which means jsonpath expression:

```
jsonpath="{.spec.metrics[1].resource.targetAverageValue}"
```

as you have metrics under spec which is a list you have to use index number which is 1 in this case.